# Retrieve data from database using key in the view file

Tags: laravel

I am trying to retrieve data from my database and show it in my view but there I get an error.

Here is my controller

```
public function index()
{            
  $Page=Superior::all();

  return view('Myview.Firstpage')->with('Task',$Page);
}
```

And this is where I assign in the view

```
<body>
<p>this is our first page </p>

{{ $Task }}


</body>
</html>
```

but this task is creating error and it says that the Task is an undefined variable my whole page looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>This is our first page </title>
</head>
<body>
<p>this is our first page </p>

{{ $Task }}


</body>
</html>
```

Superior is the name of my model from which I want to retrieve my data.

My routes files in web.php is

```
<?php




Route::get('First',function(){
    return view('Myview.Firstpage');
});
```

i am learning laravel

Comment: try `@foreach ($Task as $t) {{$t->title}} @endforeach`

Comment: instead of title in `$t->title` use your task keys

Comment: `$Task` suggest you want a single instance, but using `::all()` will get every instance in a Laravel array known as a `Collection`. If you want a single record, use `::first()`. Also, `{{ $Task }}` will print the whole variable to the screen. You probably don't want that, so you need to loop (as suggested), or, if `$Task` is a single record, use `{{ $Task->attribute }}`

Comment: Undefined variable: Task (View: C:\lara\www\Blog\resources\views\Myview\Firstpage.blade.php)   this the error i am getting even if a try just a single variable to get

Comment: Are you editing the correct file? `Firstpage.blade.php`? Do you have any `@extends()` calls in that view?

Comment: the only error that i am facing is {{ $Task }} which i passed as an key to retrieve my data in Firstpage.blade.php

Comment: You're not using the Controller, your route just returns the view. Either use a/the Controller in your route or move your Controller@index logic to your route function

Comment: return view('Myview.Firstpage','SuperiorController@index'); is this is the correct way  to call the index method of controller?? cause it is then i am getting an error which says array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the index method of your controller

```
public function index()
{

     return view('Myview.Firstpage')->with('tasks',Superior::all());

}
```

Keep in mind that the all() method returns a collection which you want to loop through in your view.

In your view, you should have:

```
    @foreach($tasks as $task)

         {{ $task->title }}

    @endforeach
```

You need to also update your route to make use of the controller:

```
Route::get('/', 'TaskController@index');
```

You could visit https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-all to learn more about collections.

Comment: Undefined variable: tasks (View: C:\lara\www\Blog\resources\views\Myview\Firstpage.blade.php)

Comment: Could you `dd(Superior::all());` in your index to see if it returns a collection. Also ensure you have the Superior model imported in your controller `use App\Superior`

Comment: ^ Neither of those suggestions would have anything to do with the variable being passed to the view.

Comment: yes tim this is what is so confusing . can u suggest something ?how i can remove this error in my view ??

Comment: Abiola my brother i am using use App\Superior

Comment: It seems the variable is not being populated in the view which is why it is undefined. Could you update the question with your routes file.

Comment: the only error that i am facing is {{ $Task }} which i passed as an key to retrieve my data in Firstpage.blade.php

Comment: Your route should be `Route::get('First', 'TaskController@index');` (need to specify the method being used, and the correct route) but otherwise, that looks to have been the issue.

Comment: return view('Myview.Firstpage','SuperiorController@index'); is this is the correct way to call the index method of controller cause it is then  i am getting an error which says array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

Comment: No @Zaeem Follow the index method and Route as defined in my answer

Comment: thank you so much both of you guys are amazing thank you for listening and helping me out i have resolved my issue with the help of you guys :)

Comment: yes my bro it works as i wanted to, thank u so much bro :)

Comment: you can help me by upvoting my answer and accepting it as the best answer. Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hi please try to pass you variable to view like this:

```
$Tasks = Superior::all();
return view('Myview.Firstpage', compact('Tasks'));
```

And then use a loop in your view like suggested in above comments.

```
   @foreach($Tasks as $task)

     {{ $task->title }}

 @endforeach
```